# Angular 8 - Replace image URL with inline base64 on production build

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am trying to change all the images of a certain page from a file path to base64, I read that sens Angular 6 we can no longer add custom code to Webpack configurations, and I am not interested in using a custom builder like **@angular-builders/custom-webpack** as a solution.

is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really need this change? I don't prefer this method at all as it will make the bundle / bundles much bigger than supposed, this will decrease your website performance

Comment: the way my project is built is that I am using angular universal with google Cloudflare, I am caching my pages and i don't have many images on my website, it is like 1 image per landing page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Node script as the following:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const base64Img = require('base64-img');

fs.readFile('my/file/path', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err);
  }
  const matches = data.match(/assets\/.*?(svg|png)/g);
  matches.forEach(match => {
    try {
      if (fs.existsSync(match)) {
        const convertedImage = base64Img.base64Sync(match);
        data = data.replace(match, `${convertedImage}`);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error: File not found', match);
    }
  });

  fs.writeFile('my/destination/file', data, 'utf8', (err) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.error(err);
    }
  });
});
```

In this way, it will get the file that you need to replace the files, search for the assets, then convert the images to base64 and replace them. The last step is to write the result to a new file.

To run this, you need to install `base64-img` library: `npm i base64-img --save-dev`. Afterwards, you can build the project and then run `node include-images.js`.

To make it easier, you can also add a script in your package.json, something like:

```
"replace-images": "ng build && node include-images.js"
```

This can be run using: `npm run replace-images`

Please note that I don't prefer converting the images into base64 and include it in the bundle as it will make the bundle / bundles much bigger and will decrease your website performance.